# How do I deeply traverse a JSON-like data structure to return a total of something

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, functional-programming

I apologize for the vague question.  Hopefully my example adds some clarity to my question... 
So I have a hierarchical data structure like this:

```
var Company = {
    root: {
        title: 'CEO',
        employees: [{
            title: 'Vice President',
            employees: [{
                title: 'Sales Lead'
            }, {
                title: 'Marketing Lead'
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

My question is how would I find out the total number of employees in the root object?  Visually, one can see that there are 3 employees in the company.  I am working with recursion to try and solve this problem, but I just can't seem to get it working right... or working at all for that matter.  I appreciate any help, tips, or advice :)

Comment: Can you show the code which you already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` with a named function that can be called recursively. The base case would be if an object has no employees.

```
const totalEmployees = Company.root.employees.reduce(countEmployees, 0);

function countEmployees(prev, next) {
    // count *this* employee
    let sum = prev + 1;
    if (next.employees && next.employees.length) {
      // count any nested employees
      sum += next.employees.reduce(countEmployees, 0);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **recursive function** to loop though a nested object structure.

Here is how you do it.

```
function countEmployee(root){

    if(!root.employees){
        return 0;
    }

    var numOfEmployee = root.employees.length;; 

    var count = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<numOfEmployee; i++){
        count = count + countEmployee(root.employees[i]);
    }

    numOfEmployee = numOfEmployee + count;

    return numOfEmployee;
}

countEmployee(Company.root); //return 3
```